# Corrections to CMakeList.txt file for Google testing?

Tags: c++, cmake, include, googletest

I have been looking at examples of CMake to help me build my project with its test folder. The main issue is that I have to include all the *test/*.cpp* files in my test folder into *tests/main.cpp* for the tests to run. I think I should include my tests with the `add_test` call in my *test/CMakeLists.txt*. Below is my current CMakeLists file:

> enable_testing()
>
> find_package(GTest REQUIRED)
>
> add_executable(test main.cpp)
>
> target_include_directories(test PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../include)
>
> target_link_libraries(test MainProjectLib ${GTEST_LIBRARIES})

And my *main.cpp* is the following.

```
#include "file_in_test1.cpp"
#include "file_in_test2.cpp"
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

I read some examples that use the standard CTest library for unit testing, but I am using Google Test. **I would like to be able to run `cmake`, `make`, and then `./test` to run all test methods found in *file_in_test1.cpp* and *file_in_test2.cpp* without having to directly import those files into *test/main.cpp*.** What additions to *CMakeLists.txt* do I have to make?

Answer (score 0):

The one line you could add at the end would be:

```
gtest_discover_tests(test)
```

This is a replacement for `gtest_add_tests` since cmake version 3.10, and then after you build everything, you can just run `ctest` and it will give you a nice summary of the tests it just ran. You can read more about this option [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/GoogleTest.html).

Also, just as a note, it would probably be better to make individual test files for each of the tests you have, rather than including the .cpp files in your main test file.

What I generally do is define an option to allow for testing and a function that creates the test I need (see below):

```
option(build_all_tests "Build all unit tests in the test directory." OFF)

if (build_all_tests)
    include(CTest)
    include(GoogleTest)

    enable_testing()

    ## Function to create a new test based off the pre-defined naming template ##
    function(new_test testname interiorDirectory)
        add_executable(${testname} ${interiorDirectory}/${testname}.cpp)

        target_link_libraries(${testname} ${GTEST_LIBRARIES})

        gtest_discover_tests(${testname}
                        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${interiorDirectory})
    endfunction(new_test)

    ## Locate GTest ##
    find_package(GTest REQUIRED)
    include_directories(${GTEST_INCLUDE_DIRS})

    ## Create all tests ##
    new_test(test1 test/test1)
    new_test(test2 test/test2)
    ...
endif()
```